# What are some of the resources a space station could produce?

Tags: science-based, space, space-colonization, asteroids

I'm making a board game set on a space station near the asteroid belt. I'm trying to come up with a few resource that space station could be producing, to export to Earth.

Here are some I came up with already.
There's a lot of **metal** in the asteroids.
Some asteroids are made up of a lot of **water** - which could be harvested, or be split into **hydrogen and oxygen**. Which could be used in **rocket fuel**. Hydrogen peroxide could be used as **propellant**.

**Pharmaceuticals** grown in zero gravity - Exomedicines, have potent properties.

Other than that, I'm kind of stumped.

Comment: This is probably better asked on [Board & Card Games StackExchange](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Hans*! This question looks quite opinion-based to me as you are the only one to judge what makes a good answer. I don't really see objective criteria to rate answers against each other. Could you please [edit] your answer to provide some clarification? If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

**NOOO,**

There is no point in exporting "goods" to the planet, it's incredibly expensive. The real value in making things in space is so you dont have to spend the energy getting it there.

So a space station near an asteroid belt that could make more space crafts would be invaluable.

Anything you could make in space you could more easily make on a planet. With exception to certain technological research.

But fundamentally, the sole value of making anything in space is to reduce the extremely high importation cost of bringing in that thing.

**EDIT- An off the deep end answer:**

It can be an interstellar space port which would effectively act as customs between planets and stars. Thus the goods that would be passed to the planet from the station would be foreign trade goods (exotic species in particular) that could not be made there.

Answer (score 1):

**Tourism**

Most people would save all the money they have to visit a space station and have an adventure in zero gravity. Some acomodations a few chessy attractions and you are set.

**No regulations Labs**

You are in space, there is no law in here. Rent a full equiped lab and start doing any research you wish without any of those pesky ethics, morals, even laws getting in your way.

**Zero G sports**

Football in space, where just grabbing the ball could make you score in your own net. 
Synchronized swimming in a water bubble traveling inside the stadium trying to do the craziest stunts posible.

People would just pay per view, and most of the profit would go to the station.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think ores from the asteroids would be the big one.

I don't splitting water into hydrogen and oxygen and shipping this to Earth would be practical. Earth has a lot of water. Wouldn't it be cheaper to get it on Earth than to ship it from the asteroids?

There was some discussion a few years back about manufacturing processes which could be done better in a weightless environment. Some pharmaceuticals, some ideas for other things where gravity makes the product have an uneven consistency, i.e. thicker at the bottom, and this is undesirable. Nice idea, though people were hard-pressed to come up with examples that would be worth the shipping cost. Granted the bulk of the cost is getting raw materials to orbit. If you start with raw materials from asteroids, many more processes would become economically viable. If we assume that the cost of getting things into orbit has been reduced -- which is probably essential to be able to get people to these asteroid colonies -- then what's the advantage of making something at the asteroids and shipping to Earth, versus making in Earth orbit?

Sorry, I seem to be shrinking your list rather than adding to it.

The only thing I can think to add: energy from solar power. I haven't done the math, but I think that's getting pretty thin at the asteroids, so that may not be very practical either.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the things that I can think of:

1. **Energy** - solar converted to microwaves and beamed back to earth.  Water split into hydrogen and oxygen for refueling vehicles in
   space.  It is easier and safer to ship water and convert it at a
   central waypoint for refueling vehicles.
2. **Finished Goods** - it can use microgravity to produce goods that are worth more than the raw materials.  Otherwise, I'd just drop the
   raw goods onto the planet.
3. **People** - people are expensive to lift off the planet.  If you can make some in orbit, you save a lot of money.